# Update auto_now field in bulk_update

Tags: django, django-models, bulkupdate

I'm using Django 2.2 and I have a model with `auto_now` `modification_datetime` field and I need to update it during/after a `bulk_update` execution only for the affected registries that were really updated.

Is it possible to update `auto_now` datetime model field only on the affected records by `bulk_update` execution?

Comment: Can you post some code to show exactly what you're doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No as [`bulk_update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update) does not call `save()` method nor it fires `pre_save` and `post_save` signals on instance ( generally produces only single update query). Also generally there is no recollection of the instances that are actually updated in Django

furthermore as documented [`auto_now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) does not trigger on update()/bulk_update() as it is triggered by `save()`

> The field is only automatically updated when calling Model.save(). The
> field isn’t updated when making updates to other fields in other ways
> such as QuerySet.update(), though you can specify a custom value for
> the field in an update like that.

You could check which instances have update manually and update their timestamp or do some kind of database trigger

Answer (score 3):

Maybe override your update method in QuerySet helps. But I am not sure if this only updates "updated_at" on data which have really changed in bulk update.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class YourModelQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def update(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['updated_at'] = timezone.now()
        super().update(**kwargs)

class YourModel(models.Model):
    objects = YourModelQuerySet.as_manager()

    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
    other_fields = ...
```

Edit:

look also here: https://brobin.me/blog/2020/02/auto-updated-timestamp-fields-in-django-bulk-querysets/